# how to stop the loop in while in python?

Tags: python, while-loop

i tried to do a while loop in which after the user inputs 'no' then the loop will stop and end the program but it did not work and i can't find the problem

```
finish = True
while (finish) :
    kg = float(input('Enter kg: '))
    total = kg * 2.2
    print('The converted kg is: ', total, 'lbs')
    question = input('do you want to quit?')
if question == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'YES':
    finish = False
    print('Bye-Bye')
else :
    print('OK!')
```

this is the code and when the user typed 'no' it should end the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Damian Robert said, the indentation on your `if/else` statements was off

However there are better ways to exit to loop, namely with a `break` statement inside the `while` loop

This exits the loop at its current iteration, meaning you don't need to set `finish` to be `False`, probably saving time as the program doesn't have to run another iteration of the loop and check the variable again. While this won't make any difference in a small script like this, it is best practise for future code

I have also changed the code regarding the user's input, it now should convert the str to lowercase then check if the letter `y` is present in the str - this just reduces the chance of the user inputting the response incorrectly

```
import sys

finish = True
while finish:
    kg = float(input('Enter kg: '))
    total = kg * 2.2
    print(f'The converted kg is: {total}lbs')
    question = input('Do you want to quit?')
    if 'y' in question.lower(): #converts str to lowercase to compare whether it contains the str 'y'
        #finish = False #not needed here unless you need to access it later in the script
        print('Bye-Bye!')
        break #exit the while loop
    else:
        print('OK!')
        continue #restart loop, not actually needed as will continue to next iteration naturally, but can improve readability

print('Exiting Program')
sys.exit(0) #program will end naturally here, so `sys.exit(0)` isn't really needed but it can improve readability
```

Hope this helps ツ

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your identation is off. The `if`/`else` statement is not ran inside the loop but after it. Modify your code like so:

```py
finish = True
while (finish) :
    kg = float(input('Enter kg: '))
    total = kg * 2.2
    print('The converted kg is: ', total, 'lbs')
    question = input('do you want to quit?')
    if question == 'Yes' or 'yes' or 'YES':
        finish = False
        print('Bye-Bye')
    else :
        print('OK!')
```